# How can I middle align text and images in table row

Tags: html

I want to middle align the following - how can I do that:

```html
<div class="container-fluid" style="height:100%">
    <table id="PulseTable" class="display2" style="height:100%">
        <tbody id="PulseBody" style="height:100%"><tr class="pulseheader">
<td class="pulseheader" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">Manager</td>
</tr>
<tr class="pulseline" style="height: 20px;">
<td class="pulseline" style="padding-left: 40px; font-size: 12px; font-style: normal;">Header</td>
<td class="pulseline" style="padding-left: 20px; font-size: 12px; font-style: normal;">New York II</td>
<td class="NONE" style="padding-left: 20px;"><img src="http://blog.sckyzo.com/wp-content/google-small.png" style="height: 30px; width: auto;"></td>
</tr>
        <tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To center them horizontally within each table cell, use:

```
text-align: center;
```

To center them vertically (this only works with tables, or elements with `display: table-cell`):

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Apply these styles to the `<td>` element.

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
          Foo bar
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No - the second one does not work. The first is not what I wanted

Comment: Did you apply the styles to the `<td>` element? I added an example to the answer

Answer (score 0):

I hope it works for you

```
.container-fluid{
position:relative;
margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use COLSPAN to merge the cell in the first line and also use CSS style "text-align: center" to align it do center:

```html
<div class="container-fluid" style="height:100%">
    <table id="PulseTable" class="display2" style="height:100%">
        <tbody id="PulseBody" style="height:100%"><tr class="pulseheader">
<td class="pulseheader" colspan="3" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center">Manager</td>
</tr>
<tr class="pulseline" style="height: 20px;">
<td class="pulseline" style="padding-left: 40px; font-size: 12px; font-style: normal;">Header</td>
<td class="pulseline" style="padding-left: 20px; font-size: 12px; font-style: normal;">New York II</td>
<td class="NONE" style="padding-left: 20px;"><img src="http://blog.sckyzo.com/wp-content/google-small.png" style="height: 30px; width: auto;"></td>
</tr>
        <tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That is not middle aligned -  is it?